# Expressing pandas subsetting operation using pipe

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way I can express the pandas operations below using the pipe operator?

```
 df_a = df[df.index.year != 2000]
 df_b = df_a[(df_a['Month'].isin([3, 4, 5])) & (df_a['region'] == 'USA')]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why would you want to use `pipe` for this operation.

`pipe` is intended to make easier syntax for chained processing of DataFrame with a chain of functions that **modify** incoming DataFrame ([see docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/basics.html?highlight=pipe#tablewise-function-application)).

What you are trying to do is to **filter** DataFrame with a number of filters (or masks).

Just to illustrate that using `pipe` for this operation is somewhat cumbersome:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.np.random.seed(123)
# Generate some data
dates = pd.date_range('2014-01-01', '2015-12-31', freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame({'region':pd.np.random.choice(['USA', 'Non-USA'], len(dates))}, index=dates)
df['Month'] = df.index.month
print df.head()

             region  Month
2014-01-31      USA      1
2014-02-28  Non-USA      2
2014-03-31      USA      3
2014-04-30      USA      4
2014-05-31      USA      5
```

Your original filter would yield:

```
df_a = df[df.index.year != 2014]
df_b = df_a[(df_a['Month'].isin([3, 4, 5])) & (df_a['region'] == 'USA')]
print df_b

           region  Month
2015-03-31    USA      3
2015-05-31    USA      5
```

Here is how you could use `pipe` to get the same output:

```
def masker(df, mask):
    return df[mask]

mask1 = df.index.year != 2014
mask2 = df['Month'].isin([3, 4, 5])
mask3 = df['region'] == 'USA'

print df.pipe(masker, mask1).pipe(masker, mask2).pipe(masker, mask3)

           region  Month
2015-03-31    USA      3
2015-05-31    USA      5
```

However pandas is able to process filtering in a rather simple (in this particular case) way:

```
print df[mask1 & mask2 & mask3]

           region  Month
2015-03-31    USA      3
2015-05-31    USA      5
```