# Expressing pandas subset using pipe

Tags: python, pandas, pipe

I have a dataframe that I subset like this:

```
   a  b   x  y
0  1  2   3 -1
1  2  4   6 -2
2  3  6   6 -3
3  4  8   3 -4

df = df[(df.a >= 2) & (df.b <= 8)]
df = df.groupby(df.x).mean()
```

How do I express this using the pandas pipe operator?

```
df = (df
      .pipe((x.a > 2) & (x.b < 6)
      .groupby(df.x)
      .apply(lambda x: x.mean())
```

Comment: I don't see why using `pipe` would be useful here. `df[(df.a >= 2) & (df.b <= 8)].groupby('x').mean()` will do the same thing, will it not?

Comment: that is true @jme, this is a toy example and in my larger code, I have more steps. Plus the `.` operator makes everything look neater.

Comment: This is either deja vu or [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045805) :-)

Comment: Essentially, "How to put a `filter` step inside a `pipe`?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you can categorize a step as something that returns a DataFrame, and takes a DataFrame (with possibly more arguments), then you can use `pipe`. Whether there's an advantage to doing so, is another question.

Here, e.g., you can use

```
df\
    .pipe(lambda df_, x, y: df_[(df_.a >= x) & (df_.b <= y)], 2, 8)\
    .pipe(lambda df_: df_.groupby(df_.x))\
    .mean()
```

Notice how the first stage is a lambda that takes 3 arguments, with the 2 and 8 passed as parameters. That's not the only way to do so - it is equivalent to

```
    .pipe(lambda df_: df_[(df_.a >= 2) & (df_.b <= 8)])\
```

Also note that you can use

```
df\
    .pipe(lambda df_, x, y: df[(df.a >= x) & (df.b <= y)], 2, 8)\
    .groupby('x')\
    .mean()
```

Here the lambda takes `df_`, but operates on `df`, and the second `pipe` has been replaced with a `groupby`.

- The first change works here, but is gragile. It *happens* to work since this is the *first* pipe stage. If it would be a later stage, it might take a DataFrame with one dimension, and attempt to filter it on a mask with another dimension, for example.
- The second change is fine. In face, I think it is more readable. Basically, anything that takes a DataFrame and returns one, can be either be called directly or through `pipe`.

Comment: thanks @Ami, you use `df_` in your lambda, would just `df` work too?

Comment: and also, can I still have .groupby not .pipe(lambda... .groupby)?

Answer (score 4):

I believe this method is clear with regard to your filtering steps and subsequent operations.  Using `loc[(mask1) & (mask2)]` is probably more performant, however.

```
>>> (df
     .pipe(lambda x: x.loc[x.a >= 2])
     .pipe(lambda x: x.loc[x.b <= 8])
     .pipe(pd.DataFrame.groupby, 'x')
     .mean()
     )

     a  b    y
x             
3  4.0  8 -4.0
6  2.5  5 -2.5
```

Alternatively:

```
(df
 .pipe(lambda x: x.loc[x.a >= 2])
 .pipe(lambda x: x.loc[x.b <= 8])
 .groupby('x')
 .mean()
 )
```

Comment: thanks @Alexander, can I still have .groupby not .pipe(pd.DataFrame.groupby, 'x') i.e. same way of using .groupby as in my code above

Answer (score 1):

You can try, but I think it is more complicated:

```
print df[(df.a >= 2) & (df.b <= 8)].groupby(df.x).mean()
     a  b  x    y
x                
3  4.0  8  3 -4.0
6  2.5  5  6 -2.5


def masker(df, mask):
    return df[mask]

mask1 = (df.a >= 2)
mask2 = (df.b <= 8)     

print df.pipe(masker, mask1).pipe(masker, mask2).groupby(df.x).mean()
     a  b  x    y
x                
3  4.0  8  3 -4.0
6  2.5  5  6 -2.5
```