# Aggregate dataframe using less repetitive code than a bunch of select and merge operations

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, merge, aggregate

I am trying to summarize/aggregate a dataframe as follows. While the code gives the correct result, it is very repetitive and I would like to avoid that. I think that I need to use something like `groupby`, `agg`, `apply`, etc. but could not find a way to do that. The goal is to compute `df_summ` at the end. I think that I am using too many intermediate dataframes with selections of rows, and too many `merge`s to put the results together. I feel that there must be a simpler way, but cannot figure it out.

The real `df_stats` input dataframe has millions of rows, and `df_summ` output dataframe has dozens of columns. The input shown below is just a minimal reproducible example.

```
import io
import pandas as pd

TESTDATA="""
enzyme  regions   N   length
AaaI    all       10  238045
AaaI    all       20  170393
AaaI    all       30  131782
AaaI    all       40  103790
AaaI    all       50  81246
AaaI    all       60  62469
AaaI    all       70  46080
AaaI    all       80  31340
AaaI    all       90  17188
AaaI    captured  10  292735
AaaI    captured  20  229824
AaaI    captured  30  193605
AaaI    captured  40  163710
AaaI    captured  50  138271
AaaI    captured  60  116122
AaaI    captured  70  95615
AaaI    captured  80  73317
AaaI    captured  90  50316
AagI    all       10  88337
AagI    all       20  19144
AagI    all       30  11030
AagI    all       40  8093
AagI    all       50  6394
AagI    all       60  4991
AagI    all       70  3813
AagI    all       80  2759
AagI    all       90  1666
AagI    captured  10  34463
AagI    captured  20  19220
AagI    captured  30  15389
AagI    captured  40  12818
AagI    captured  50  10923
AagI    captured  60  9261
AagI    captured  70  7753
AagI    captured  80  6201
AagI    captured  90  4495
"""


df_stats = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(TESTDATA), sep='\s+')

df_cap_N90 = df_stats[(df_stats['N'] == 90) & (df_stats['regions'] == 'captured')].drop(columns=['regions', 'N'])
df_cap_N50 = df_stats[(df_stats['N'] == 50) & (df_stats['regions'] == 'captured')].drop(columns=['regions', 'N'])

df_all_N50 = df_stats[(df_stats['N'] == 50) & (df_stats['regions'] == 'all')     ].drop(columns=['regions', 'N'])

df_summ_cap_N50_all_N50 = pd.merge(df_cap_N50, df_all_N50, on='enzyme', how='inner', suffixes=('_cap_N50', '_all_N50'))
df_summ_cap_N50_all_N50['cap_N50_all_N50'] = (df_summ_cap_N50_all_N50['length_cap_N50'] -
                                              df_summ_cap_N50_all_N50['length_all_N50'])
print(df_summ_cap_N50_all_N50)

df_summ_cap_N90_all_N50 = pd.merge(df_cap_N90, df_all_N50, on='enzyme', how='inner', suffixes=('_cap_N90', '_all_N50'))
df_summ_cap_N90_all_N50['cap_N90_all_N50'] = df_summ_cap_N90_all_N50['length_cap_N90'] - df_summ_cap_N90_all_N50['length_all_N50']
print(df_summ_cap_N90_all_N50)


df_summ = pd.merge(df_summ_cap_N50_all_N50.drop(columns=['length_cap_N50', 'length_all_N50']),
                   df_summ_cap_N90_all_N50.drop(columns=['length_cap_N90', 'length_all_N50']),
                   on='enzyme', how='inner')
print(df_summ)
```

Prints:

```
  enzyme  length_cap_N50  length_all_N50  cap_N50_all_N50
0   AaaI          138271           81246            57025
1   AagI           10923            6394             4529
  enzyme  length_cap_N90  length_all_N50  cap_N90_all_N50
0   AaaI           50316           81246           -30930
1   AagI            4495            6394            -1899
  enzyme  cap_N50_all_N50  cap_N90_all_N50
0   AaaI            57025           -30930
1   AagI             4529            -1899
```

**Notes on bioinformatics background behind this question:**

*(Feel free to skip this, it describes the domain knowledge behind the python code)*

The above code is one step in a multi-step bioinformatics project, where I try to find optimal restriction enzymes based on the way they cut DNA.

As input for this step, I have a table with restriction enzymes (whose name is stored in column `enzyme`). I want to rank the enzymes based on the statistical properties of the way the cut DNA. Column `regions` stores two different DNA regions types, which I want to differentiate using these enzymes. Column `N` is the name of the statistic that measures the degree of how finely the DNA is cut (N10, ..., N90), and `length` is the value of this statistic. The `N` statistics summarize the DNA fragment length distribution, measured in units of nucleotides), similar in spirit to quantiles (10%, ..., 90%). When I compare the the enzymes, I want to do simple operations, such as `cap_N90_all_N50 = { captured N90 } - { all N50 }`, etc. Then I rank the enzymes by the combination of `cap_N50_all_N50`, etc.

Comment: You say "df_summ output dataframe has dozens of columns". What are these other columns? Presumably ideally you'd like to generate them all at the same time? Also are there only ever 2 regions, or do you want stats for more regions?

Comment: @Nick These other columns are similar in spirit to the ones I showed in the [mre]. I can figure them out myself once the [mre] solution is posted. But there are only two values of `regions`, as shown.

Comment: OK, the reason I asked is that all the answers you've got are series-based; it's possible that dependent on the complete results you want that an array-based solution might be more optimal.

Comment: @Nick Thank you for the comments and for the answer! I am so glad I asked this question here. I truly learned a lot from you and others who kindly posted solutions!

Comment: @Nick As for the array-based solution: the code in even the first answer, by *Timeless*, is fast enough. I am looking for **different** ways to do it. If anything, not faster, but rather easier to maintain or simpler or shorter. Thanks again!

Comment: That makes perfect sense. But it is possible that an array-based solution might be shorter and easier to understand (and thus hopefully also easier to maintain). Anyway, I'm glad you're getting some useful information out of this - I have had good results with bounties that I've put on my questions too.

Comment: I tested the answers, and the 3 best ones all worked fine for me (those by *Timeless*, *Nick* and *cottontail*). The most unusual answer is probably the one by *cottontail*, who got the bounty. I really wish I could split the bounty between all 3 answers equally! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't describe the logic and I can't understand why you don't compute `df_all_N90`.

That being said, to get your expected output, you can can try a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) / [`sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) :

```
piv = (df_stats.loc[df_stats["N"].isin([50, 90])]
       .pivot(index="enzyme", columns=["regions", "N"], values="length"))

out = (piv["captured"].sub(piv[("all", 50)], axis=0)
           .add_prefix("cap_N").add_suffix("_all_N50").reset_index())
```

Output :

```
print(out)

N enzyme  cap_N50_all_N50  cap_N90_all_N50
0   AaaI            57025           -30930
1   AagI             4529            -1899

[2 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Groupby and Aggregate

We first groupby multiple columns - 'enzyme', 'regions', 'N'. This groups all the stats for each enzyme, region and N value into one aggregate row.

The .agg() aggregates the length column by just taking the first value for each group. We no longer need the repetitive filtering from earlier. All the data is pre-grouped.

```
    gb = df_stats.groupby(['enzyme', 'regions', 'N'])  

    stats = gb.agg(length=('length', 'first')).reset_index()
```

Pivot for Comparison

The stats dataframe has one row for each stat. We pivot it into columns for easier comparison:

```
    pivoted = stats.pivot(index='enzyme',  
                  columns=['regions', 'N'], 
                  values='length')
```

Now all the length values are aligned by column, split by N and regions.

Vectorized Column Operations

We can directly take column differences on the pivoted dataframe:

```
    pivoted['cap_N50_all_N50'] = pivoted['captured']['50'] - pivoted['all']['50']
```

The differences are taken for the FULL column in one vectorized operation, avoiding row-wise loops.

Final Summarized Output

We output just the difference columns needed into a clean summary dataframe:

```
    df_summ = pivoted[['cap_N50_all_N50','cap_N90_all_N50']]
```

Output:

```
       cap_N50_all_N50  cap_N90_all_N50
enzyme                                   
AaaI                 57025           -30930
AagI                  4529            -1899
```

Comment: These two operations appear to be unnecessary: `gb = df_stats.groupby(['enzyme', 'regions', 'N'])` and `stats = gb.agg(length=('length', 'first')).reset_index()`. They just result in the same dataframe as the input `df_stats`.

Comment: Typo here, change string `'50'` to int `50`. Wrong: `pivoted['cap_N50_all_N50'] = pivoted['captured']['50'] - pivoted['all']['50']`. Right: `pivoted['cap_N50_all_N50'] = pivoted['captured'][50] - pivoted['all'][50]`

Comment: After the statement above, add the missing statement:
`pivoted['cap_N90_all_N50'] = pivoted['captured'][90] - pivoted['all'][50]`

Comment: At the very end, add these missing statements: `df_summ.columns = [f'{a}_{b}'.strip('_') for a, b in df_summ.columns]` and `df_summ = df_summ.reset_index()`. They change column names from tuples into strings, and `enzyme` from index into proper column, respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Note that your answer required a few changes to work in my hands. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be to convert `df_stats` into a MultiIndex Series, filter the relevant rows and subtract `regions='all'` and `N=50` values from the filtered rows by `enzyme`. Then what remains is to unstack the Series back into a dataframe.

```py
out = (
    df_stats
    .set_index(['enzyme', 'regions', 'N'])['length']
    .pipe(lambda x: x.loc[:, 'captured', [50, 90]].sub(x.loc[:, 'all', 50], level='enzyme'))
    .droplevel('regions')
    .unstack()
    .add_prefix('cap_N').add_suffix('_all_N50')
    .reset_index()
)
```

The dataframe goes through the following transformation:

[image: result]

Comment: This is a very curious and non-obvious alternative solution! It worked fine for me, thank you.

Comment: I found these links useful when going through the code. The `pipe` method is neat! See also: [pandas.DataFrame.pipe — pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html), [Expressing pandas subset using pipe - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687205/expressing-pandas-subset-using-pipe)

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility. Find the `all` region `N50` values for each enzyme, subtract those from the `captured` values and then pivot the result back to columns for each combination:

```py
all_N50 = df_stats[(df_stats['regions'] == 'all') & (df_stats['N'] == 50)].set_index('enzyme')['length']

dfe = df_stats[df_stats['regions'] == 'captured'].set_index('enzyme').drop(columns='regions')

dfe['length'] = dfe['length'].sub(all_N50, level='enzyme')

df_summ = dfe.pivot(columns='N', values='length')
df_summ.columns = pd.Series([f'cap_N{col}_all_N50' for col in df_summ], name='')
df_summ = df_summ.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  enzyme  cap_N10_all_N50  cap_N20_all_N50  cap_N30_all_N50  cap_N40_all_N50
0   AaaI           211489           148578           112359            82464  \
1   AagI            28069            12826             8995             6424

   cap_N50_all_N50  cap_N60_all_N50  cap_N70_all_N50  cap_N80_all_N50
0            57025            34876            14369            -7929  \
1             4529             2867             1359             -193

   cap_N90_all_N50
0           -30930
1            -1899
```

Comment: This is a nice alternative solution, thank you! It worked for me fine.

Comment: @TimurShtatland no worries - I'm glad you found it useful.