# Aggregate dataframe using simpler (vectorized?) operations instead of loops

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate, vectorization

I have a piece of code that works correctly (gives the expected answer), but is both inefficient and unnecessarily complex. It uses loops that I want to simplify and make more efficient, possibly using vectorized operations. It also converts a dataframe to a series and then back into a dataframe again - another code chunk that needs work. In other words, I want to make this piece of code more pythonic.

I marked the problematic places in the code (below) with comments that start with `# TODO:`.

The goal of the code is to summarize and aggregate the input dataframe `df` (which has the distributions of DNA fragment lengths for two types of regions: `all` and `captured`). This is a bioinformatic problem, part of a larger project that ranks enzymes by their ability to cut certain DNA regions into pieces of defined length. For the purpose of this question, the only relevant information is that `length` is integer and there are two types of DNA `regions`: `all` and `captured`. The aim is to produce the dataframe `df_pur` with purity *vs.* `length_cutoff` (the cutoff of length when purifying the DNA). The steps are:

- Compute the fraction of the total length for each type of `regions` that is above each of the `length_cutoffs`.
- Find the ratio of this fraction: `captured / all` for each of the `length_cutoffs` and store the result in a dataframe.

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

# This is a minimal reproducible example. The real dataset has 2
# columns and 10s of millions of rows. Column 1 is integer, column 2
# has 2 values: 'all' and 'captured':
TESTDATA="""
length   regions
     1       all
    49       all
   200       all
    20  captured
   480  captured
  2000  captured
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(TESTDATA), sep='\s+')

# This is a minimal reproducible example. The real list has ~10
# integer values (cutoffs):
length_cutoffs = [10, 100, 1000]

df_tot_length = pd.DataFrame(columns=['tot_length'])
df_tot_length['tot_length'] = df.groupby(['regions']).length.sum()
df_tot_length.reset_index(inplace=True)

print(df_tot_length)

#     regions  tot_length
# 0       all         250
# 1  captured        2500


df_frc_tot = pd.DataFrame(columns=['regions', 'length_cutoff', 'sum_lengths'])
regions = df['regions'].unique()
df_index = pd.DataFrame({'regions': regions}).set_index('regions')

# TODO: simplify this loop (vectorize?):
for length_cutoff in length_cutoffs:
    df_cur = (pd.DataFrame({'length_cutoff': length_cutoff,
                            'sum_lengths': df[df['length'] >= length_cutoff]
                            .groupby(['regions']).length.sum()},
                           # Prevent dropping rows where no elements
                           # are selected by the above
                           # condition. Re-insert the dropped rows,
                           # use for those sum_lengths = NaN
                        index=df_index.index)
              # Correct the above sum_lengths = NaN to 0:
              .fillna(0)).reset_index()
    # Undo the effect of `fillna(0)` above, which casts the
    # integer column as float:
    df_cur['sum_lengths'] = df_cur['sum_lengths'].astype('int')
    # TODO: simplify this loop (vectorize?):
    for region in regions:
        df_cur.loc[df_cur['regions'] == region, 'frc_tot_length'] = (
            df_cur.loc[df_cur['regions'] == region, 'sum_lengths'] /
            df_tot_length.loc[df_tot_length['regions'] == region, 'tot_length'])
    df_frc_tot = pd.concat([df_frc_tot, df_cur], axis=0)

df_frc_tot.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

print(df_frc_tot)

#     regions length_cutoff sum_lengths  frc_tot_length
# 0       all            10         249           0.996
# 1  captured            10        2500           1.000
# 2       all           100         200           0.800
# 3  captured           100        2480           0.992
# 4       all          1000           0           0.000
# 5  captured          1000        2000           0.800

# TODO: simplify the next 2 statements:
ser_pur = (df_frc_tot.loc[df_frc_tot['regions'] == 'captured', 'frc_tot_length']
           .reset_index(drop=True) /
           df_frc_tot.loc[df_frc_tot['regions'] == 'all',      'frc_tot_length']
           .reset_index(drop=True))
df_pur = pd.DataFrame({'length_cutoff': length_cutoffs, 'purity': ser_pur})

print(df_pur)

#    length_cutoff    purity
# 0             10  1.004016
# 1            100  1.240000
# 2           1000       inf
```

**Note:**

**I am primarily interested in making the code more clear, simple and pythonic.**

Among the answers that are tied for the above, I will prefer the more efficient one in terms of speed.

I have 8 GB available by default per job, but can increase this to 32 GB if needed. To benchmark efficiency, please use this real life-size example dataframe:

```
num_rows = int(1e7)
df = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame({'length': np.random.choice(range(1, 201),   size=num_rows, replace=True), 'regions': 'all'}),
    pd.DataFrame({'length': np.random.choice(range(20, 2001), size=num_rows, replace=True), 'regions': 'captured'}),
]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Related: [Aggregate dataframe using less repetitive code than a bunch of select and merge operations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77586425/967621)

Comment: Given that this is a performance question, do you mind giving a some more representative sample data? For example, you could sample length from a [power law distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.powerlaw.html), and make 5 million of each type of test data.

Comment: @NickODell Thank you for the comment! Updated the question with a **Note** at the end, and added a real-life size example for benchmarking. Just to repeat, for me the most important criteria are for the code to be clear, simple and pythonic. Efficiency is secondary. I have access to a large cluster, and other steps in the complex workflow are **much** more computationally heavy than this script. It's mostly when I see too many loops instead of vectorized ops in pandas, it may often signal that something is very, very wrong. :)

Comment: I tested the 2 top answers that are in my subjective opinion the most pythonic, simplest and clearest ones (by *cottontail* and *Andrej Kesely*). Both methods were very close by these most important criteria. The method from *cottontail* was slightly simpler.

Comment: I benchmarked these methods by speed. The method from *cottontail* was  the fastest (2.7 sec), followed by the method posted in the OP question (3.8 sec) , followed by that from *Andrej Kesely* (13 sec). All times were measured on M1 MacBook Pro, Python 3.11.6, pandas 2.1.4, with 1 warmup, followed by the median of 3 repetitions. I wish I could split the bounty equally, but since this is not possible, I accepted one answer and awarded the bounty to another answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
length_cutoffs = [10, 100, 1000]

df["bins"] = pd.cut(
    df["length"],
    pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks([-np.inf] + length_cutoffs + [np.inf], closed="left"),
)

out = df.pivot_table(index=["regions", "bins"], values="length", aggfunc="sum")

g = out.groupby(level=0)
out["frc_tot_length"] = (
    g["length"].transform(lambda x: [x.iloc[i:].sum() for i in range(len(x))])
) / g["length"].sum()
print(out)
print()
```

This prints:

```
                          length  frc_tot_length
regions  bins                                   
all      [-inf, 10.0)          1           1.000
         [10.0, 100.0)        49           0.996
         [100.0, 1000.0)     200           0.800
         [1000.0, inf)         0           0.000
captured [-inf, 10.0)          0           1.000
         [10.0, 100.0)        20           1.000
         [100.0, 1000.0)     480           0.992
         [1000.0, inf)      2000           0.800
```

Then:

```py
x = out.unstack(level=0)
x = x[("frc_tot_length", "captured")] / x[("frc_tot_length", "all")]
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
bins
[-inf, 10.0)       1.000000
[10.0, 100.0)      1.004016
[100.0, 1000.0)    1.240000
[1000.0, inf)           inf
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the loop over `length_cutoffs` can be replaced by `pivot_table`. The condition to filter the sub-dataframe (`df[df['length'] >= length_cutoff]`) can be replaced by `pd.cut` to cut the data into bins and the `groupby.sum` inside the loop can be replaced by `cumsum` operation on the pivot table.

Since we now have a pivot table, the captured / all ratio can be handled vectorially by dividing one row by the other. The rest is more-or-less cosmetic, sorting by length cutoffs, convert into dataframe etc.

```py
tot_lens = df.groupby('regions')['length'].sum()
df_pur = (
    df
    .pivot_table(
        index='regions', 
        columns=pd.cut(df['length'], [*length_cutoffs, float('inf')], labels=length_cutoffs), 
        values='length', 
        aggfunc='sum')
    .iloc[:, ::-1].cumsum(axis=1)
    .div(tot_lens, axis=0)
    .pipe(lambda x: x.loc['captured'] / x.loc['all'])
    .sort_index()
    .rename_axis('length_cutoff')
    .reset_index(name='purity')
)
```

The sequence of transformations the data goes through is as follows:

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

I see the issue - getting both efficiency and readable code.
I'd keep the loop over length_cutoffs and vectorize the rest,
something like this (which completes in under 10 seconds on 1e7 records
running on a Raspberry Pi)

```py
length_cutoffs = [10, 100, 1000]
# Total length by region
df_tot_length = df.groupby(['regions'])['length'].sum().reset_index().\
                    rename(columns={'length':'tot_length'})

def proc_one_cutoff(length_cutoff):
    dfsel = df[df['length'] >= length_cutoff]
    df_cur2 = dfsel.groupby('regions')['length'].sum().\
                    reset_index()        # Sum length by region
    df_cur2 = df_cur2.merge(df_tot_length, on='regions', how='right', 
                           validate='m:1') # Fills in missing rows
    df_cur2['length_cutoff'] = length_cutoff
    df_cur2['length'] = df_cur2['length'].fillna(0).astype(int)
    df_cur2['frc_tot_length'] = df_cur2['length'] / df_cur2['tot_length']
    df_cur2 = df_cur2.drop(columns=['tot_length'])
    return df_cur2

df_frc_tot = pd.concat([proc_one_cutoff(length_cutoff) for length_cutoff in length_cutoffs])

df_pur = df_frc_tot.pivot_table(values='frc_tot_length',index='length_cutoff',
                                columns='regions').reset_index()
df_pur['purity'] = df_pur['captured'] / df_pur['all']
```

Answer (score 1):

**1 - `df_frc_tot` calculation steps : proposed script with comments and for one value of length_cutoffs**

Following snippet is only for one value of `length_cutoff`, but obviously you could do a loop for instance in case of several values (iteration of a list for instance).

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#### YOUR DUMMY DATAFRAME ####
num_rows = int(1e7)
df = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame({'length': np.random.choice(range(1, 201),   size=num_rows, replace=True), 'regions': 'all'}),
    pd.DataFrame({'length': np.random.choice(range(20, 2001), size=num_rows, replace=True), 'regions': 'captured'}),
]).reset_index(drop=True)
#########################

# Minimal reproducible example : [5, 8]
length_cutoffs = 5

# Add a temporary column to indicate if length is below or above the cutoff
df['length_cat'] = df['length'].ge(length_cutoffs).astype(int)

# Compute the sum of lengths above each cutoff for each region
sum_lengths = df.groupby(['regions', 'length_cat'])['length'].sum().unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)

# Rename the columns
sum_lengths.columns = [f"< {length_cutoffs}" if x == 0 else f"> {length_cutoffs}" for x in sum_lengths.columns]
#### >>> sum_lengths
####              < 5          > 5
#### regions                      
#### all       498310   1004627630
#### captured       0  10100975858

# Compute the total length for each region
tot_lengths = df.groupby('regions')['length'].sum().rename('tot_length')
#### >>> tot_lengths
#### regions
#### all          1005125940
#### captured    10100975858
#### Name: tot_length, dtype: int64

# Compute the fraction of total length for each region and cutoff
frc_tot_length = sum_lengths.divide(tot_lengths, axis=0)
#### >>> frc_tot_length
####                < 5       > 5
#### regions                     
#### all       0.000496  0.999504
#### captured  0.000000  1.000000

# Build results dataframe
df_frc_tot = (pd.concat([sum_lengths[[f"> {length_cutoffs}"]], 
                 tot_lengths, 
                 frc_tot_length[[f"> {length_cutoffs}"]]], axis=1)
       .assign(length_cutoffs=length_cutoffs)
       )
df_frc_tot.columns = ['sum_lengths', 'tot_lengths', 'frc_tot_length', 'length_cutoffs']
df_frc_tot = df_frc_tot[['length_cutoffs', 'tot_lengths', 'sum_lengths', 'frc_tot_length']]
#### >>> df_frc_tot
####           length_cutoffs  tot_lengths  sum_lengths  frc_tot_length
#### regions                                                           
#### all                    5   1005125940   1004627630        0.999504
#### captured               5  10100975858  10100975858        1.000000
```

**2 - `df_frc_tot` calculation steps : proposed script without comments and within a loop for a list of length_cutoffs**
(vectorized and optimized version)

This snippet uses your dummy dataframe as for efficiency measurement

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#### YOUR DUMMY DATAFRAME ####
num_rows = int(1e7)
df = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame({'length': np.random.choice(range(1, 201),   size=num_rows, replace=True), 'regions': 'all'}),
    pd.DataFrame({'length': np.random.choice(range(20, 2001), size=num_rows, replace=True), 'regions': 'captured'}),
]).reset_index(drop=True)
#########################

length_cutoffs = [10, 50, 100]
col_names = ['sum_lengths', 'tot_lengths', 'frc_tot_length', 'length_cutoff']
ordered_col_names = ['length_cutoff', 'tot_lengths', 'sum_lengths', 'frc_tot_length']

def frc_tot_calculation(length_cutoff):
    df['length_cat'] = df['length'].ge(length_cutoff).astype(int)
    sum_lengths = (
                     (df.groupby(['regions', 'length_cat'])['length']
                        .sum()
                        .unstack()
                        .fillna(0)
                        .astype(int)
                       ).drop(0, axis=1) # Optimization : get rid of useless columns
                        .rename(columns={1: f"> {length_cutoff}"})
                    )
    tot_lengths = df.groupby('regions')['length'].sum().rename('tot_length')
    frc_tot_length = sum_lengths.divide(tot_lengths, axis=0)
    res = (pd.concat([sum_lengths[[f"> {length_cutoff}"]], 
                     tot_lengths, 
                     frc_tot_length[[f"> {length_cutoff}"]]], axis=1)
           ).assign(length_cutoff=length_cutoff)
    res.columns = col_names
    return res[ordered_col_names]

df_frc_tot = (pd.concat([frc_tot_calculation(length_cutoff) for length_cutoff in length_cutoffs], axis=0)
                .reset_index()
                )

print(df_frc_tot)
#### >>> df_frc_tot
####     regions  length_cutoff  tot_lengths  sum_lengths  frc_tot_length
#### 0       all             10   1005188577   1002939982        0.997763
#### 1  captured             10  10099004348  10099004348        1.000000
#### 2       all             50   1005188577    944004934        0.939132
#### 3  captured             50  10099004348  10093770488        0.999482
#### 4       all            100   1005188577    757658893        0.753748
#### 5  captured            100  10099004348  10074965450        0.997620
```

**3 - `Purity` readable calculation steps**

```py
# Select lines for 'all' and 'captured' regions
all_rows = df_frc_tot[df_frc_tot['regions'].eq('all')].reset_index(drop=True)
captured_rows = df_frc_tot[df_frc_tot['regions'].eq('captured')].reset_index(drop=True)
#### >>> all_rows
####   regions  length_cutoff  tot_lengths  sum_lengths  frc_tot_length
#### 0     all             10   1005188577   1002939982        0.997763
#### 1     all             50   1005188577    944004934        0.939132
#### 2     all            100   1005188577    757658893        0.753748

#### >>> captured_rows
####     regions  length_cutoff  tot_lengths  sum_lengths  frc_tot_length
#### 0  captured             10  10099004348  10099004348        1.000000
#### 1  captured             50  10099004348  10093770488        0.999482
#### 2  captured            100  10099004348  10074965450        0.997620

# Calculate the ratio of 'frc_tot_length' values ​​between 'all' and 'captured' regions
purity = all_rows['frc_tot_length'].div(captured_rows['frc_tot_length'])
#### >>> purity
#### 0    0.997763
#### 1    0.939619
#### 2    0.755546
#### Name: frc_tot_length, dtype: float64

# Create a DataFrame with cutoff lengths and purity
df_pur = pd.DataFrame({'length_cutoff': all_rows['length_cutoff'], 'purity': purity})
#### >>> df_pur
####    length_cutoff    purity
#### 0             10  0.997763
#### 1             50  0.939619
#### 2            100  0.755546
```